# Connection issues with KVM on RHEL6.5 to Licence Server

Tags: rhel, kvm

I currently have a RedHat 6.5 kvm running under a RedHat 6.5 host.  I am attempting to make a connection to a Rational Apex licence server on the local network, however the connection times out before licence provision.

I currently have a bridged network interface and have already setup packet forwarding, and am successfully able to ssh the VM

Is there any particular testing that I should use to determine the issue?